# How to get the "Name Box" name of an Excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have a cell in Excel for which I have assigned a variable name, `this_cells_name`, to a cell, `D2`, by using the Excel Name Box.

Here is an example of what the Excel Name Box is:

[image: The Excel Name Box]

I want to be able to point to that cell and get the variable name as a return value.

I know how to do the following:

- use `=CELL("address",D2)` and get `"$D$2"` as a return value,
- use `=CELL("address",this_cells_name)` and get `"$D$2"` as a return value.

I want to do the following:

- use `=some_function(D2)` and get `"this_cells_name"` as a return value.

How can I do this? A VBA solution would be fine.

Comment: What is a "name box"?

Comment: @roryap I have edited my question to answer you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get a Range to return its Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630496/how-do-you-get-a-range-to-return-its-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use

```
Dim var as variant
on error Resume Next
var=Range("D2").Name.Name
on error goto 0
if IsEmpty(var) then msgbox "Cell has no name"
```

The error trapping is to handle the case where the cell has no name

Comment: I don't think its recent: since my hard disk crashed I can only go back to Excel 2003 but that has Range.Name (IIRC it goes back to at least Excel97).  The trick is to use Name.Name since the default property of a Name object is its refersto formula.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Public Function WhatsInAName(r As Range) As String
    WhatsInAName = ""
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Range(n).Address(0, 0) = r.Address(0, 0) Then
            WhatsInAName = n.Name
        End If
    Next n
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: What do you think of using `r.Name.Name`? Actually, I see that as an accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3630587/293078