# Returning a custom named range's name from selected target

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro-enabled spreadsheet with several named ranges, with vba references to those named ranges (I use named ranges rather than the default so that I can move them around without breaking all of my references). What I want to do is to be able to pull the custom name of the cell that is selected by the user in a SelectionChange event. What I have right now is:

```
Select Case Target.Name
Case "A"
...etc,
```

However, Target.Name only returns the A1-style name of the cell, and not the custom name that is assigned to the cell. Is there any other property that I should be using? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630496/how-do-you-get-a-range-to-return-its-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need the `Name` property of the `Name` object:

```
Select Case Target.Name.Name
```