# Get Named Range From Row Number

Tags: vba, excel

My worksheet contains rows that have been assigned named ranges. For example, row 10 of sheet(1) has been named "Kumquats". I want to write a function that returns the name of the named range when the row # is passed to it. So the function call would be:

```
getRowNamedRange(rowNum as integer) as string
```

and the function would return the string "Kumquats" if passed the number 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630496/how-do-you-get-a-range-to-return-its-name) it is one line no need for separate  function

Comment: yes, that was the key concept, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to the reference supplied by Scott something like the following might do:

```
Public Function getRowNamedRange(rowNum as integer) as string
    getRowNamedRange = Activesheet.rows(rowNum).Name.Name
End Function
```