# VBA named range retrieves as sheetname and cell address

Tags: vba, excel

I have a routine that adds new customer ranges to an estimate and actual sheet along with validation, formulas and protection. I add named ranges to certain cells as they are used throughout the sheets in formulas.

The code part that names the ranges is as follows (it works, the ranges are named correctly as seen in name manager)

The function that does the name ranging is declared as so

```
Function InitializeAddedRange(rangeToFormat As Range, _
    custName As String, currentSheet As Worksheet)
```

and is called as follows

```
 Call InitializeAddedRange(startCell, customerName, sourceWorksheet)
```

so in the snippet below rangeToFormat is startCell

```
Set rangeToFormat = rangeToFormat.Offset(0, 1)
If currentSheet.Name = "Actual Quarterly Sales" Then
    rangeToFormat.Name = Replace(custName, " ", "") & "ActualBasePrice"
    rangeToFormat.Offset(0, 1).Name = Replace(custName, " ", "") & "ActualIsCurrent"
ElseIf currentSheet.Name = "Quarterly Sales Projections" Then
    rangeToFormat.Name = Replace(custName, " ", "") & "BasePrice"
    rangeToFormat.Offset(0, 1).Name = Replace(custName, " ", "") & "IsCurrent"
End If
```

In a function that is called in the same subroutine but AFTER the code above,
I am trying to retrieve the name of the range as its required in numerous formulas. (startCell.Name)

```
Set tempRange = Range(startCell.Offset(1, 3), startCell.Offset(1, 14))
For Each cCell In tempRange
    With cCell
        .Value = 0
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=DrumGallons*" & startCell.Name & "*R[-1]C"
        .Locked = True
    End With
Next cCell
```

The problem is `startCell.Name` returns the sheetname and cell address i.e. **SalesEstimates$B$12** instead of the named range which should be **customernameBasePrice**. I've done a lot of VBA work and I can't recall ever coming across this problem. Does this occur because the subroutine hasn't finished and the named range actually hasn't changed within excel yet before the function is trying to access it? I don't think that can be it but I've tried numerous things none of which work.

Comment: rangeToFormat is startCell, its passed as parameter to the function...I'll edit the post..As an aside, I noted that the range naming was working correctly in the original post, it was the name retrieving that was not.

Comment: Apparently, there's a [difference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823060.aspx) between workbook and worksheet names. Edit: also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630496/how-do-you-get-a-range-to-return-its-name)?

Comment: @ findwindow post that as the answer and Ill accept...it is Name.Name to retrieve the name and just Range.Name =.... to set it

Comment: Thanks but you can just upvote the answer in my link^_^

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it so I'm just trying to recall it. try using

```
Name(startCell)
```

To obtain the name attached to the Range reference

Comment: @dinotom: did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to address the name object

```
rng.Name.Name
```

Comment: @dinotom comments don't last forever, and I didn't read them. Whatever, I'll make this a wiki, I'm not trying to steal someone's rep or anything.