# How to return NAME of the cell (not address, content, etc.)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Let's say I name cell C4 as "TestCell", using NameManager or typing into the Name Box.

I want C5 to have a formula to return "TestCell" without the quotes.

I'll take VBA answer if that's necessary for this.

Comment: Try this: https://superuser.com/questions/683825/formula-return-cell-defined-name

Comment: Thanks Daghan, was really hoping for a simple formula but it looks like VBA is the way to go!

Comment: the linked code creates a formula to use in Excel , so i guess you get a mix :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for, about a few hours of digging:
[How do you get a Range to return its Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630496/how-do-you-get-a-range-to-return-its-name)

use the .Name.Name method worked for me (using one .name gives only address).

Good luck!